# How to use only one GPU for tensorflow session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, tensorrt

I have two GPUs.
My program uses TensorRT and Tensorflow.

When I run only TensorRT part, it is fine.
When I run together with Tensorflow part, I have error as

```
[TensorRT] ERROR: engine.cpp (370) - Cuda Error in ~ExecutionContext: 77 (an illegal memory access was encountered)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nvinfer1::CudaError'
  what():  std::exception
```

The issue is when Tensorflow session starts as follow

```
self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
self.persistent_sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph, config=tf_config)
```

It loads two GPUs as

```
2019-06-06 14:15:04.420265: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6965 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Quadro P4000, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-06-06 14:15:04.420713: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 7159 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Quadro P4000, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

I tried to load only one GPU as

(1)Putting on top of the python code

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```

(2)

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    self.persistent_sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph, config=tf_config)
```

Both don't work.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 12):

I could manage to load only one GPU be placing the following lines at the first line of the python code.

```
import sys, os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```

Comment: Right, this really needs to be set before *any* interaction with CUDA occurs. Note that it's usually a good practice to avoid putting this directly in your code. Rather, you can start your script with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python3 myScript.py`. This lets others use your script with more than one GPU without changing the code.